# Javascript. Check if the Object contains object

Tags: javascript

I have following two arrays of objects

```
//references
var refs=[
         {id:1,   name:'John',    state:'A'},
         {id:2,   name:'Obama',   state:'P'},
         {id:3,   name:'Lincoln', state:'P'}
];

//items
var items=[
          {ref:refs[0],    detailed:true },
          {ref:refs[1],    detailed:false}
];
```

Now I want to check if *items* contains *refs[0]* . How can I do It? Of course we can do
something like this

```
for(item:items){
 if(item.ref==refs[0]){
  console.log('contains');
  break;
 }
}
```

but I might have 2000 refs. Any ideas. Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify why that approach won't work if you have 2000 refs?

Comment: How's having more refs change anything, you're only interested in refs[0] anyway according to your specs? I would not go through a for in loop though because both items and refs are arrays so you can do `while(++i<len)` since items[?].refs is a reference you can compare with like this `===`

Comment: No, it works. It just seems to me wasting resources.

Comment: @JumabekAlihanov - See my comment to Juhana under my answer.

Comment: Still not sure what the requirements are, if you only need to look up one item once then a loop is the way to go but if you have a lot of refs and you need to know if they are in items and if so what the values are then you need to redefine items. I've updated my answer with a possible optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
console.log(get_ref_item(refs[0], items));

function get_ref_item(ref, items) {
    return items.filter(function fi(item){
        return ref.id == item.ref.id;
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5MfrT/

Comment: Note that this is practically identical to the original code performance-wise. There's just no way to avoid looping through the entire array when searching for elements unless you already know roughly where to start looking for.

Comment: @Juhana - From a *performance* point of view, the for with break is going to be faster in many cases, depending on where the item being searched for is in the array. So, in actuality, the OPs code is better in this regard. See: http://jsperf.com/for-vs-array-filter

Comment: Note, the only reason it *could* be equivalent (or maybe better, would have to test) is if the entire array had to be searched each time, for instance if the `ref.id` could exist more than once in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what the problem is here but assuming you'd like to know if a ref is in items and you need to know this for multiple refs (look it up multiple times) then you better re define your items:

```
//references
var refs=[
         {id:1,   name:'John',    state:'A'},
         {id:2,   name:'Obama',   state:'P'},
         {id:3,   name:'Lincoln', state:'P'}
];

//items
var items=[
          {ref:refs[0],    detailed:true },
          {ref:refs[1],    detailed:false}
];

//if you need to continiously look up a ref in items
// it's better to convert items to an object
// {"refid":{ref:..,detailed:...}}
// assuming every item has a ref and has that ref only once
// and every ref has a unique id
var i = -1,len=items.length,tmp={};
while(++i<len){
  tmp[items[i].ref.id]=items[i];
}
items=tmp;

console.log("item for refs 0:",items[refs[0].id]);
console.log("item for refs 1:",items[refs[1].id]);
console.log("item for refs 2:",items[refs[2].id]);//undefined, that ref is not it items
```

Comment: You can test your optimization against the `for` and `Array.filter` techniques here: http://jsperf.com/for-vs-array-filter Setting up performance tests can be tricky, so be sure to think it through.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm not using `for ... in` nor `Array.filter` or `while(++i<len)` because it's not using an array at all. But I can tell you right now that if you'd had 500+ items and 2000+ refs making the items an object with ref.id as keys is going to out perform whatever array lookup you're planning to do 200 times. (if op was planning to match every item with a ref)